# Word Interop app to write text to the end of an open document

Tags: c#, interop, ms-word

I'm trying to write a C# application that will find a document open in MS Word and write some text to the end of the document using word interop. Is this possible?

I know it's possible to kind of solve this problem using Process and Sendkeys built into the .NET Framework, but I'd like to solve the problem using Word Interop so I can add more functionality down the road (also sendkeys would really only solve the problem in certain special cases.)

Thanks!

Update:

I got the following partial solution working:

```
    Application wordApp = new Application();
    wordApp.Visible = true;
    wordApp.Documents.Add();
    Range rng = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0);
    rng.Text = "New Text";
```

But I'd like to use an already open instance of word instead of creating a new one. Thanks!

Update 2:

I'm close! The following code works with UAC turned off

```
    Application wordApp = (Word.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
    Range rng = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0);
    rng.Text = "New Text";
```

But I'm not sure how to get it working with UAC enabled. UAC isn't causing any errors or exceptions, it just doesn't write the text to the open document.

Thanks for everyones help so far, the end is now in sight :)!

Update 3:

Just tried it again with UAC turned on and it worked... strange. Still if you know of any good resources about interop and UAC in general, please post a link here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using `Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application")` to get the running application, rather than creating a new one?

Comment: Thanks!! Just did and that seems to be getting the open instance of word but it's not sending the text (the text was being sent via the code in the update part of my question). Could this be a UAC problem? (I'm testing on a Win 7 box)

Comment: I restarted computer with UAC disabled and it started working. I then restarted the computer again, after re-enabling UAC, tried the program again and it worked. Hopefully I'll get to the bottom of it eventually! Thanks for you answer though.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to expect UAC-related problems?  If your app and Word are both running as the same user, I don't think there would this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely Evan.  The Microsoft Office Interop Assemblies let you do just about anything from C#!  SendKeys() is an issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57(v=vs.80).aspx

I guess I should elaborate about SendKeys(): it doesn't even work reliably anymore as it was a primary hacker tool.  The MS Office Interop Assemblies allow you to do an enormous array of things with each of the Office components.  I have used them extensively with MS Excel, and some with Word, and you can do just about anything a user can do programatically.

Comment: Thanks for you help! I've gotten somewhere by following the link your provided. Now I just need to know how to hook to the active word window (see my q update). Do you know I could do that, or do you know of an example online that I've missed? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below .Here i am giving example with image insert.

```
 WordC.Application wordApp = new WordC.Application();
                //  create Word document object
                WordC.Document aDoc = null;
                object readOnly = false;
                 object isVisible = false;
                 wordApp.Visible = false;
               //  wordApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
//docFileName is the filename with complete path. ex c://test.doc

                 aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(docFileName, Type.Missing, ref readOnly, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, ref isVisible, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
aDoc.Activate();
aDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imgFilename, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                aDoc.Save();
                aDoc.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                wordApp.Quit(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```